# Failing on building a react app as docker image on multiple platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64

Tags: docker, github-actions, arm64

I have currently this code:

```yaml
name: Push Backend as Docker Image

on:
  push:
    branches: ["master"]
  pull_request:
    branches: ["master"]

jobs:
  push_to_registry:
    name: Push Docker image to Docker Hub
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check out the repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Log in to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}

      - name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v1

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1

      - name: Build and push Docker image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@ad44023a93711e3deb337508980b4b5e9bcdc5dc
        with:
          context: .
          push: true
          tags: user/docker-image:latest
          platforms: linux/amd64,linux/arm64
```

And I get this when I Github action:

```
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm install" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
Error: buildx call failed with: ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm install" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

Before I had without writing the platform attribute in the yml file, like this:

```yaml
name: Push Backend as Docker Image

on:
  push:
    branches: ["master"]
  pull_request:
    branches: ["master"]

jobs:
  push_to_registry:
    name: Push Docker image to Docker Hub
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check out the repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Log in to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}

      - name: Build and push Docker image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@ad44023a93711e3deb337508980b4b5e9bcdc5dc
        with:
          context: .
          push: true
          tags: user/docker-image:latest
```

I think the error might have come from the platform attribute I added because the code I sent above is working perfectly fine.

Error log: https://prnt.sc/gItIf-_R5HNY

Dockerfile:

```
# Use an official Node.js runtime as the base image
FROM node:16.15.1-alpine as builder

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the package.json and package-lock.json files to the container
COPY package*.json ./

# Install project dependencies
RUN npm install


# Copy the rest of the application code to the container
COPY . .

# Generate the Prisma client
RUN npx prisma generate

# # Generate the Prisma client
# RUN npx prisma migrate deploy

# Expose the port on which your Node.js application will listen
EXPOSE 4500

# Set the command to run your Node.js application
CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

Is this because of ARM64 and the problem with bcrypt:

this is some log from the error

```
     > [linux/arm64 4/6] RUN npm install:
143.3 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
143.3 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 6.2.0-1018-azure
143.3 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/app/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
143.3 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /app/node_modules/bcrypt
143.3 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v16.15.1
143.3 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.9
143.3 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
enter code here
```

Comment: What the complete error? Looks like the dependencies are not being installed correctly.

Comment: @Azeem, currently that is the error: https://prnt.sc/gItIf-_R5HNY, but if I remove the platform and use the other code snippet that I sent, it pushes to dockerhub perfectly fine and is built successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with library `bcrypt`, the solution was to remove bcrypt from package.json and install `bcryptjs`, since bcrypt has a problem with ARM64, I tried with bcryptjs works perfectly well and does not encounter any error.